# issues with gridLayout in swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

So I have these delegate methods that help me layout my collectionView. I am trying to create somewhat of a grid layout where there are X numberOfSections and X numberOfItemsInSection. Based off of what I have now it lays out all of the rights next to each other and spaces them out a little too far as to where cells go to the next line. How do I go about fitting all the cells for a section on one line.

```
 //Asks the delegate for the size of the header view in the specified section.
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return .zero
    }
    //Asks the delegate for the size of the footer view in the specified section.
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return .zero
    }
    //Asks the delegate for the size of the specified item’s cell.
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.size.width - CGFloat(numberOfItemsInSection))/2.2, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height - 50)

    }
    //Asks the delegate for the margins to apply to content in the specified section.
    //in short in controls the amount of space between the items above,left,right, and below
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    }
    //Asks the delegate for the spacing between successive rows or columns of a section.
    //controls the space in between rows and columns
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
    //Asks the delegate for the spacing between successive items of a single row or column.
    //controls the space between each cell
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
```

I feel like it has to do with the sizeForItemAt but I can't exactly figure out how to change it.

This is what it currently looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it has to do with `sizeForItemAt` method, you should use the `indexPath` parameter so you can use its property `section` to define the size for each item in each section.

Just remember that there is a space between items so you need to take that into account when calculating the width and height, so you can adjust the spacing using `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` and `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` methods.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
    }

    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.size.width - CGFloat(numberOfItemsInSection))/2.2, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height - 50)

}
```

Comment: sorry fell asleep will try this now and what made you chose 200 by 200

Comment: i also want the same size for each cell so i am not necessarily concerned with the section thing